# Variables not recognized within Rescue in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, rescue

I have the following code:

```
  rescue Timeout::Error, StandardError => e
      puts "Caught exception: #{e.message}".red
      log.puts("#{e.backtrace}")
      email_ids_all.each do |email_delete|
        call= "/api/v2/emails/#{email_delete}/"
        ......
```

Before this `rescue` piece I have defined `log` and `email_ids_all`. However, neither of these are recognized within the ruby script. If i do this:

```
 rescue Timeout::Error, StandardError => e
    File.open(rescuelogfile, 'w') do |log| #setup log to write response codes.
      puts "Caught exception: #{e.message}".red
      log.puts("#{e.backtrace}")
      email_ids_all.each do |email_delete|
        call= "/api/v2/emails/#{email_delete}/"
        ....
```

`log` works fine, which makes sense. It would take a lot of writing to redefine the `email_ids_all` array and other variables contained inside my rescue block.

Is there anyway to allow variables to be recognized inside the rescue? Basically my code is laid out like this:

```
begin

#some code

rescue
  #above code

end
```

I am using ruby 1.9.3.

EDIT----

`log` starts right after my `begin` statement :

```
begin
  File.open(logfile, 'w') do |log| #setup log to write response codes.
```

`log.puts` works throughout the entire code except when an error is thrown, and then it runs the rescue script where `log` is not available.

The same goes for `email_ids_all`. There is an API call that generates about 10,000 emails and each of them is added to the array `email_ids_all`. The script is receiving an error about halfway through generating these emails, and so I need the rescue script to delete all email ids in the `email_ids_all` array. But for whatever reason, I get the following error:

```
FS_Test_Env.rb:762:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `email_ids_all' for main:Object (NameError)
    from FS_Test_Env.rb:759:in `open'
    from FS_Test_Env.rb:759:in `rescue in <main>'
    from FS_Test_Env.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please post a complete example, it's impossible to guess what's wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: @Stefan I don't know how to post a more complete example. I can post the entire code but it's about 800 lines and I don't think anyone wants to go through all of that. I have an array, defined inside a begin loop, and an error that happens. When it rescues, the array is not available. I just need to know if that's normal, and if not, what could cause it. Seeing how I define the array and make the API calls doesn't seem to be relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of the block parameter `log` is limited to that block. This is the whole point of the `open` with block.

Maybe you want to do:

```
begin
  log = File.open('logfile', 'w')
  ...
rescue
  ...
ensure
  log.close
end
```

Note that this does not cover errors when opening the logfile.

Regarding `email_ids_all`, I guess (!) you have the exception in a statement like:

```
email_ids_all = ... a long and complex calculation which raises an exception
```

If yes, the problem is that the assignment happens only after the whole right-hand side is calculated. The var `email_ids_all` is not yet created when the exception happens.

In order to access the elements created before the exception, you have to keep track of them, e.g.

```
begin
  email_ids = []
  10000.times do 
    email_ids << ... # create element eventually raising an exception
  end
rescue
  ... # treat the already created elements
end
```

Comment: This may work for the `log` piece, but what about the `email_ids_all` array? Would I also have to define it outside the `begin`? That's not a feasible option for me as it is defined over the entire code.

Comment: No, you can as well define it "inside the begin". It just must not be local to an inner block. As you did not show where it does come from, it's hard to tell what would be the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

The way you put it, it should work, for example:

```
irb(main):001:0> begin
irb(main):002:1* x = 1
irb(main):003:1> x / 0
irb(main):004:1> rescue Exception => e
irb(main):005:1> p x
irb(main):006:1> end
1
=> 1
```

So it looks like the exception is thrown before your variables are defined.

Comment: hmm strange. See my edits above. The variables are definitely defined, I tried `puts email_ids_all` before the error happens and it prints the entire array with no issue.